# SqlDataReader returns "Enumeration yielded no results" despite entering DataReader.Read() code block

Tags: c#, sqldatareader

I have a class function where I'm trying to read data from a database table using the SqlDataReader. When the SqlCmd.ExecuteReader() is called, I see(upon debugging) that the resultView of the SqlDataReader says "Enumeration yielded no results". However, the SqlDataReader.Read() still returns true and therefore enters the while() code block.

The query executes correctly on SQL, and even changing the query to get data from other tables give the same results. Please note that I have several other functions in a separate class executing the similar code to get data from these same database tables and they work without any issue.

Another observation is that after the ExecuteReader() is called, the VisibleFieldCount field of the SQLDataReader has the value = 11, which is equal to the total number of columns in the Customer table. This suggests that the reader is able read atleast some of the data from the database.

Any suggestions or help will be appreciated. Please let me know if any more information is required.

I have tried simplifying the function code as much as possible by removing any code logic other than the data retrieval part for the ease of debugging.

```
 public bool MatchPassword(string username, string enteredPassword)
{
    bool loginSuccessful = false;
    string returnedpasswordbinary;
    DatabaseConnection databaseConnectionObj = new DatabaseConnection();
    databaseConnectionObj.CreateDBConnection(); //Sets the connection string and opens database connection
    string query = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Customers WHERE CustomerID='ALFKI';";
    SqlCommand sqlCommandObj = new SqlCommand();
    sqlCommandObj.CommandText = query;
    sqlCommandObj.Connection = databaseConnectionObj.SqlConnectionObj1;
    try
    {
        SqlDataReader sqlDataReaderObj = sqlCommandObj.ExecuteReader();
        if (sqlDataReaderObj.HasRows)
            {
                while (sqlDataReaderObj.Read())
                {
                    returnedPasswordBinary = sqlDataReaderObj[0].ToString();
                }
            }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    return loginSuccessful;
}
```

Comment: have you tried with wihout where condition? top 10 like

Comment: @cdev I have, it still displays the same behavior even with the simplest query "SELECT * FROM dbo.Customers;".

Comment: Is it works with other tables? I am not clear that point in your question

Comment: @cdev Exhibits the same behavior with other tables as well. Though executing the same queries on SQL Server itself returns the expected data without any issues.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What behaviour are you expecting and what actually happens? Keep in mind that enumerating the data reader changes the data reader, so you shouldn't do that in the debugger - you're throwing the data away.

Comment: add command parameters to your query, "WHERE CustomerID= @CustomerID" cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", "ALFKI"), and try again pls

Comment: Guys just to update. I made no changes to the code whatsoever, but it started working on its own now. I'm not sure if windows updates or something else in the environment changed that might have resolved it, but it has been a couple of days now and it's working fine. I'll post an update in case it breaks again.
Thank you for all the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please set [commandtype](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtype?view=netframework-4.8)

```
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
```